# Из listBox берётся сразу несколько элементов вместо одного

Tags: c#, listbox

Есть постоянный поток, который получает от сервера данные и вставляет в ListBox.

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
 {
     edits.Insert(0, ( new edit() { // мои данные }));
 }
```

Всё работает, однако при клике зачастую (не всегда!) выбирается сразу несколько элементов. Хотя режим установлен в Single.

```
private void Queue_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single;
            var editItem = myListBox.SelectedItem as edit;
            if (editItem == null)
                return;
            edits.Remove(editItem);
        }
```

В чём может быть проблема и как её исправить? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Вы должны установить мод Single до того, как пользователь сделает выбор.

Comment: @mirypoko Нет, итог тот же. Да что там, я этим Single обвешался как шаман дохлыми крысами. И после инициализации компонентов, и в свойствах самого элемента.  [Тут что-то похожее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843784/listbox-is-selecting-many-items-even-in-selectionmode-single), но решение проблемы до меня не дошло.

Comment: Честно говоря маловато данных. У вас Forms или Wpf? И код инициализации или xaml показать бы. Код добавления элементов, в общем всё, что связанно с listbox. То, что вы приводите - это лишь вызов функции удаление из какого-то списка выбранного элемента. Этого не достаточно, чтобы сказать в чем проблема, потому что в том, что вы показали проблем нет

Comment: Могу не исключать, что это баг вашей версии платформы, если у вас одна из ранних по умолчанию. Я сталкивался например с нерабочей привязкой свойства Text у TextBox по PropertyChanged. Оказалось, что это был баг платформы до версии 3.5 или 4.0 (не помню), поэтому переход на более свежую версию решил проблемы. А способ из статьи вам скорее всего не поможет, там, как я понял, проблема в списке string. Из-за способа работы net со строками каждый одинаковый string ссылается на один и тот же экземпляр строки, поэтому лист считает их одним элементом.

Comment: @John wpf, но в нескольких местах вызываются компоненты форм. [Вот сам проект](https://github.com/SiarheiGribov/SWViewer) (MainWindow). Я просто сомневаюсь, что кто-то станет смотреть чужой отборный говнокод. P.S.: для понимания сути: прога получает правки из сотен разделов Википедий, фильтрует их и некоторые заносит в очередь в listBox, чтобы юзер мог их проверить.

Comment: Нет, версия не ниже 4, всё «из коробки».

Comment: Это последняя версия? Не вижу у listbox выставленного в xaml свойства SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single. В первую очередь там нужно выставить это свойство, а в других местах смысла трогать нет.